# How to include (referencing) CSS Javascript jQuery in master page and content (child) page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a HTML template that have a lot of jQuery, CSS references in each page, I am trying to using master but had a hard time to figure out what to put and where to put those references, good thing is that the template tell us which are global level and which are page level requirements.

I tried to put those global thing in master page and those sub things in content page but they are not worked (apparently those "**STYLE**" in head tag are work but those "**SCRIPT**" in bottom of body tag are not (I used "console" in developer mode of web browser and got "**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**"), one more thing is there are lots of redundant references in both SCRIPT and also STYLE, please advise me to find the best way to build master page and child page, if you can give me an example of a structure in master page and content page that would be great.

Here are example of 2 original HTML template pages: (I deleted some unnecessary parts in body) so you can have an idea of what I am trying to archive.

**Homepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />

   <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->          
   <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->

   <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES --> 
   <link href="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />              
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/revolution_slider/css/rs-style.css" media="screen">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/revolution_slider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen"> 
   <link href="assets/plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />                
   <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->

   <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES --> 
   <link href="assets/css/style-metronic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/themes/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
   <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <!-- END THEME STYLES -->

   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>   

    <!-- SOME BODY CONTENTS -->

    <!-- Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time -->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS(REQUIRED FOR ALL PAGES) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>  
    <![endif]-->  
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/hover-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>    
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JAVASCRIPTS(REQUIRED ONLY FOR CURRENT PAGE) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution_slider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution_slider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/index.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            App.init();    
            App.initBxSlider();
            Index.initRevolutionSlider();                    
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JAVASCRIPTS -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

**Contact.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />

   <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->          
   <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->

   <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES --> 
   <link href="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />               
   <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->

   <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES --> 
   <link href="assets/css/style-metronic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/themes/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
   <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <!-- END THEME STYLES -->

   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>

    <!-- SOME BODY CONTENTS -->

    <!-- Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time -->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS(REQUIRED FOR ALL PAGES) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>  
    <![endif]-->  
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/hover-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>    
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JAVASCRIPTS(REQUIRED ONLY FOR CURRENT PAGE) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/gmaps/gmaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/contact-us.js"></script>  
    <script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
           App.init();
           ContactUs.init();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JAVASCRIPTS -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

Comment: You have only showed us some `HTML` markup, where is your actual `.aspx` master page and content page so that we can see what you have tried??.

Comment: Is your Contact page inheriting your master page? Inherits="MyMAster.aspx" I assume you are using asp?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of attention, for the past hour I tried to fix it and it works fine now. I was about to show the master page markup code but since I modify it continuously, the errors are also changing. BIGGEST problem is that I DID NOT realize ORDER of codes does MATTER, BIG MATTER, no matter where you put those STYLE and SCRIPT in master or child page, they have to be in exactly order (ex: global things must be presented before those page-level things...) as in your HTML template. I followed it and it WORK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIGGEST problem is that I DID NOT realize **ORDER** of codes does MATTER, BIG MATTER, no matter where you put those **STYLE** and **SCRIPT** in master or child page, they have to be in exactly order (ex: global things must be presented before those page-level things...) as in your HTML template. I followed it and it WORK now.

Here basic master page structure I did:

```
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">

      //Put your PAGE REQUIRED STYLE HERE in your content (child page)

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
    <link href="~/assets/css/style-metronic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/themes/red.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME STYLES -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <!-- END HEAD -->
</head>

<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>

    // PUT WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO PUT HERE
    // PUT WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO PUT HERE

    <!-- Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time -->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS(REQUIRED FOR ALL PAGES) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>  
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/hover-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            //Put your PAGE REQUIRED SCRIPT HERE in your content (child page)

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    // PUT WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO PUT HERE
    // PUT WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO PUT HERE

</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```